# Convert .txt file to integer in Python 3.7.3

Tags: python-3.x

I need to turn a .txt file with a single number into a variable with the type 'int'.
This is my code so far:

```
   coinBalance = open.('coinBalance', 'r')

   coinBalance = str(coinBalance)

   coinBalance = int(coinBalance)
```

And it gives the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='coinBalance' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"`

Comment: what is your real code? `open.(...` isnt valid syntax

Comment: You are trying to convert the string representation of a file object (not the contents) to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Moosefeather, you're trying to cast a filepointer to a string and int instead of reading the contents and casting them. The code below will read the contents of the file 'coinBalance' and then cast that string to an int.

```
coinBalance = int(open('coinBalance').read())
```